# python package won't read

Tags: python, package

I need to use pandas, and similar package in my project. Since, I switched computer it has been a rough transition. After I downloaded atom again the IDE I prefer. I can't get it to work, atom doesn't seem to be able to read pandas, however, pretty sure the terminal is able to (picture 1). "Pip 3 freeze" shows me all the package, including pandas. I tried uninstalling atom and package and downloading anaconda, hence the frustration.

Thank you for the help //Adil

[in the terminal I can read the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ezg.png)

[when I import the package It won't read it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IL9o.png)

Comment: I am not an Atom user. However, I would guess that the problem is that the python version Atom is configured to use is different than the environment you are using on the command line. Perhaps Atom is not being told to use the downloaded Anaconda interpreter and is using the default interpreter on your computer?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's the case, I looked up the version of python in atom and it says 2.7 and in anaconda "terminal", 3.8.

Comment: I just need to figure out how to change it in atom!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, after the advice I got from the guy above. I did some research, since, I had anaconda installed I needed to find the "path", to the installed version. Considering that I'm on a Mac, I opened the terminal (probably the same in windows)and wrote "where python", it gave my a path to "Anaconda python3". In atom, I -script option- set up profile- pasted the path.